# how to determine whether app.config file exists

Tags: c#, app-config

Is there a way to find out whether an app.config file exists, without using "File.Exists"?
I tried

```
if ( !ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.ElementInformation.IsPresent )
{...}
```

but IsPresent is false even if app.config with a connection string exists.

Edit:
Did I misinterpret the IsPresent Property?

Comment: what wrong with `File.Exist` ?

Comment: It would be a cleaner code to have something like "ConfigurationManager.IsPresent" instead of "System.IO.File.Exists( System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location + ".config" )"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `AppDomain` reports on where it expects the configuration file for the application to reside. You can test if the file actually exists (with no need for dummy AppSettings, and no need to try and work out what the configuration file should be called, or where it is located):

```
public static bool CheckConfigFileIsPresent()
{
   return File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
}
```

Comment: Seems to work and much cleaner than accepted answer IMHO, thank you.

Answer (score 9):

You can create method in static class

```
public static class ConfigurationManagerHelper
{
    public static bool Exists()
    {
        return Exists(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
    }

    public static bool Exists(Assembly assembly)
    {
        return System.IO.File.Exists(assembly.Location + ".config" )
    }
}
```

And then use where you want

```
ConfigurationManagerHelper.Exists();  // or pass assembly
```

Comment: This will fail when the entry point was unmanaged, for example in unit tests.

Answer (score 3):

Most simple way that I can think of is to add some "dummy" application setting flag then check for that flag, e.g.:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dummyflag"]))
{
  //config file doesn't exist..
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. Do you know for what is IsPresent for?

Comment: @ibr cheers, glad it's working! Sorry, first time I see that property and the only thing said about it in the documentation is `Gets a value indicating whether the associated ConfigurationElement object is in the configuration file` - dunno why it returned false for ConnectionStrings.

Comment: Instead of setting a "dummy" flag, why not just check via an index i.e. `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[0])`?

Comment: @gvee didn't think of that when writing the answer but you got a point... will look into it and update the answer if needed.

Comment: @gvee - If the file doesn't exist and you check via index, you'll get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Comment: Also, I don't get how this will check for the existence of a file. If you have app.config but no key called "dummyFlag" in the appSettings section, this will tell you that the file does not exist.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb true, so this is more like checking for a required configuration value than checking for actual file.