# Ensuring that App.config Exists Before Using It

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to determine whether app.config file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297170/how-to-determine-whether-app-config-file-exists)

Is there a way to ensure that an App.config exists before trying to access a value? I don't want to run into a situation where I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object error" when I do this:

`machineName = appConfig.AppSettings.Settings["MachineName"].Value;`

If my App.config could not be found, I'm not sure how I would know if it exists or the appConfig object is properly populated. I have tried

`if (appConfig.AppSettings.Settings.Count == 0) { // do something }`

But I am not sure if this is the best approach.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297170/how-to-determine-whether-app-config-file-exists

Answer (score 4):

Rather than checking that App.config exists or not, why not just perform a null check on the value?  The error is occurring when you call the method on a null value.

```
if (appConfig.AppSettings.Settings["MachineName"] != null)
{
    machineName = appConfig.AppSettings.Settings["MachineName"].Value;
}
```