# Check whether the app.config file exists or not in console app C#

Tags: c#, console, app-config

I create a console app in C#. I want to use an `app.config` file in my project.

My problem is: before reading from `app.config`, I want to make sure that the `app.config` exists. How to check it?

Please help me! Thanks all

Comment: Try searching first, please.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297170/how-to-determine-whether-app-config-file-exists

Answer (score 1):

While you could simply use `if( File.Exists( Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location + ".config" ) )` it is a bit hackish and brittle and doesn't work if the config file is in another directory.

I think the best approach is to try to load the configuration explicitly and catch an exception (for want of a `.ConfigurationExists` property), like so:

```
try {
    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
} catch(ConfigurationErrorsException) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your get and set methods of your app.config property (or if you have multiple properties) you can make sure if the file exists first by calling File.Exists(path). If it doesn't, you can throw an exception if you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.85).aspx